# need help update a datatable cell value

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datatable

I have a trivial question about updating a datatable `MyDT`. I googled and found several approach and got compile errors. Here is the code and here is what I tried with the error. Any help is greatly appreciated. BTW, I am using asp.net framework 2.0 and VB.NET

```
MyDT.Rows[1][4] = "4NF" '  Property access must assign to the property or use it value

row.Item("New_Column") = "4NF" ' Input string was not in a correct format.
```

> Couldn't store <4NF> in New_Column Column. Expect type is Byte.

```
row["New_Column"] = "4NF" ' Expression is not a method

Dim StatusCode As String

For Each row As DataRow In MyDT.Rows
    StatusCode= row.Item("ThisColumn").ToString()
    If StatusCode= "NONF" Then
        MyDT.Rows[1][4] = "4NF"
    End If
 Next row
```

Comment: Have a look at [changing values of a column in datatable in vb.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8939398/changing-values-of-a-column-in-datatable-in-vb-net)

Comment: It tells you, `Expect type is Byte`. But you trying to stick string into it

Answer (score -1):

You should either:

- Store data as String in your DataTable
- Do a conversion

Here how the conversion looks

```
MyDT.Rows[1][4] = Convert.ToByte("4NF")
```